# Kotlin Interface function interchangeable arguments

Tags: generics, kotlin, interface

I currently work on an Interface which which has a simple function that all classes that extends this interface should implement. 
BUT the classes should be callable with different function arguments like this

```
interface IDoSomething<T> {

    fun execute(vararg any: Any?): T // Make function arguments interchangeable

}
```

```
class DoSomethingA : IDoSomething<String> {

    // This is what i want
    override fun execute(int: Int, boolean: Boolean): String {
        println("Do something with parameters: $int, $boolean")
        ...  
    }

    // This is what i need to do
    override fun execute(vararg any: Any?): String {
        val int = any[0] as Int
        val boolean = any[1] as Boolean
        println("Do something with parameters: $int, $boolean")
        ...
    }
}
```

Other classes that implement this interface should be able to have other arguments

```
class DoSomethingB : IDoSomething<String> {

    // Should also be possible with same interface
    override fun execute(string: String, double: Double, boolean: Boolean): String {
        println("Do something with parameters: $string, $double, $boolean")
        ...
    }

}
```

Is there anything in Kotlin which can help me to do thinks like this ? Or exist a pattern which helps to solve exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of an interface. You won't be able to call the function without knowing the specific implementation, so the method might as well be removed from the interface definition. But you could define a fixed set of parameters using generics and then there might be usefulness when there are multiple implementations of a specific set of parameter types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't anything already built-in in the language to achieve what you want (e.g. C++ variadic templates).

But you can still achieve what you want using a generic input and replace multiple parameters with a class which wraps them:

```kotlin
interface IDoSomething<I, T> {

  fun execute(input: I): T
}

class DoSomethingB : IDoSomething<Pair<String, Double>, String> {

  // Should also be possible with same interface
  override fun execute(input: Pair<String, Double>): String {
    val (string, double) = input
    println("Do something with parameters: $string, $double")
    ...
  }
}
```

This was the simplest solution to your problem.

You have another solution, which is more complex.

You can have an annotation (e.g. `@Input`) which accepts the types that you need to support for each implementation and then you can generate extensions of your interface with an annotation processor to have compile-time safety.

**e.g.**

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class Input(
  val types: Array<KClass<*>> = []
)

@Input(types = [String::class, Double::class])
class DoSomethingB : IDoSomething<String> {

  override fun execute(vararg any: Any?): String = execute(any) { string, double ->
    println("Do something with parameters: $string, $double")
    ...
  }
}

// With an annotation processor you can generate an extension like this.
fun DoSomethingB.execute(vararg input: Any?, block: (string: String, double: Double) -> String): String {
  val string = input[0] as String
  val double = input[1] as Double
  return block(string, double)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Nice solution. 
I will go with the simple one. But the one with the annotations is also very interesting